# Debugger source line synchronization not working in IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3 on Windows 8 with the Scala plugin 0.7.264. Scala is installed in `C:\Apps\Scala\scala-2.10.1`, and that directory is in my PATH. The Scala docs are in `C:\Apps\Scala\scala-2.10.1\doc\scala-devel-docs\api`. These are manual installs from the .zip files.

Everything seems to work fine except for two things:

First, if the "Run compile server (in external build mode)" settings is enabled (as it is by default), I get this error:

[image]

Turning off that setting fixes that for now, but there is another problem. I can run my code in the debugger and see values change in the debugger panel as I single step through the code, but it doesn't synchronize the source file view as I step through.

Normally I'd expect to see the current line being executed turn green, and the green highlight would follow along as I hit F10 or F11 to step through, but it doesn't. I can set breakpoints on source lines and let it run, and it stops at each breakpoint as expected. It just doesn't highlight the source line in green when it gets there.

Similarly, if a source file is not open (either my source code or a library file), and I step into that code, it appears to single-step correctly but does not open the source file at all.

Everything else works fine, like the autocompletes and Shift+F1 to view the Scala docs for the name the cursor is on.

The really odd thing is I had full debugging working briefly. At first I'd installed Scala from the `.msi` file, so it installed Scala into `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala`. When I set up IntelliJ to use that Scala installation I did get the green highlight on source lines as I stepped through the code.

The only problem with that setup was that IntelliJ complained about the missing `doc\scala-devel-docs\api` directory when I'd setup a Scala project, because the `.msi` installation uses a different subdirectory for the API docs. It was easy enough to fix that up manually in the Global Liraries settings, but I figured I'd try the .zip installation so I could use a directory layout more like what IntelliJ was expecting.

I should have left well enough alone! I even tried going back to that arrangement and still didn't get source line synchronization working again.

At one point I also tried letting IntelliJ do the Scala installation, but that also gave the same results: everything working except source line synchronization in the debugger.

There must be some obvious thing I got wrong, but I'm not sure what it could be. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's a screenshot from a debug session:

[image]

The program is stopped on line 3, as indicated by the values assigned to `x` and `y` but not yet to `z`, and the `<init>():3, Main$$anon$1` in the Frames panel. So line 3 should be highlighted in green but isn't.

Here are the relevant settings dialogs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above is with "Run compile server" on; as mentioned I ended up turning that setting off. The field values are the defaults, including the `-server -Xss1m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` JVM parameters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same version of IDEA and the Scala plugin (however on OS X and JDK 6), and I do not have this problem. Does this occur with any of your projects or only a specific one?

---

Assuming that the OS shouldn't be responsible, the difference is that I use sbt to build my projects. So if you are willing to set up a `build.sbt` and installing the SBT plugin for IDEA, this might be worth a try.

Although the fancy new compile server should in theory be as fast and smooth as sbt, I find it very pleasant to work with the sbt plugin. You can install it from Settings -> IDE Settings -> Plugins. Next step I also highly recommend is to use the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin, which is like the complementary to the IDEA SBT plugin—this will allow you to generate the full IDEA project files from sbt (you can have as little as a single `scalaVersion` entry in `build.sbt` if you don't need to manage dependencies, so you don't need to learn much of sbt in the first place).

The final step then is to go into your Run/Debug configuration, and change in the "Before launch" section from "Make" to "SBT".

---

Finally you might get better support for your problem through the [JetBrains online forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/scala?view=discussions).

Comment: Thanks! Those are all great tips. The same thing happens with all projects. I will try it on OSX and Linux and see if I have any better luck there. SBT sounds very powerful, although at this stage I'm really just experimenting with the language and trying to keep the environment simple. Will give it a shot though and see if it makes any difference. I'll post a note in the JetBrains forum too, probably should have thought of that in the first place. Thanks again!